# how to place time condition in this code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the block of code. The facebook page keeps loading until string "End of results" found and then this function exits. Sometimes this takes more than 30 minutes of loading therefore I want to work it like

if ( string "end of results" found OR 5 minutes passed)

so this will be bound to 5 minutes or less if string found earlier. Thank you

```
var nodes = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('_64f'));

    var bottomNode = nodes.filter(function isBottomNode(el) {
      return !!(
        el &&
        el.textContent &&
        el.textContent.indexOf('End of Results')=== 0
      );
    });
    return !!bottomNode.length;
}
```

Comment: how often is the function (though, you haven't written it as a function, it's just a stream of code) executed

Comment: I think your question is missing information. I don’t see anything in the code you posted that would cause the code to be delayed – it just does a check instantly. The way you wrote the delay is important to the solution.

Comment: Please focus on

        el &&
        el.textContent &&
        el.textContent.indexOf('End of Results')=== 0

This means that the facebook page will keep loading until this finds the string "End of results" on the page. When the string finds up than this returns boolean to the function isBottomNode(). 

My problem is that this takes upto 30, 45 minutes to loading the page of facebook. I want the function isBottomNode() to be satisfied even after 5 minutes. So this function will be satisfied in either of one case. 1-- five minutes passed or 2-- string "End of results" found.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for being late, my free times is very low.

Try code below. i have added some important descriptions to it as inline comments (you can check the result with clicking `Run code snippet` button):

```js
window.onload=function(){
    //This is the element that 'End Of Results' will add to it
    var mC = document.getElementById('must-capture');
    var ti2=setTimeout(function(){
        alert("timeout!! not found!");
    }, 10000/*for 5 minutes use 5*60*1000*/);
    var obs=new MutationObserver(function(list){
        var fnd=0;
        list.every(function(c){
            Array.prototype.every.call(c.addedNodes, function(n){
               if(n.innerHTML.indexOf("End Of Results")>-1){
                   obs.disconnect()
                   fnd=1;
                   return false;
               }
            });
            if(fnd) return false;
        });
        if(fnd) {
            clearTimeout(ti2);
            //put the codes you need here...
            console.log("It's just same time that 'End Of Results' is ready to be added!!");
        }
    });
    obs.observe(mC, { characterData: true, childList: true, subtree: true });
    
    //TIP:
    //Now we need to simulate adding new contents to page with specified intervals. one of this contents is same "End Of results" text. (this part is not needed in final project and will happen automatically as you said in your original question):
    var i=0,
        texts=["hello", "salam", "test", "sample", "tavakkol", "bttola", "End Of Results"];
    var ti=setInterval(function(){
        var d=document.createElement("div");
        d.innerHTML=texts[i++];
        mC.appendChild(d);
        if(i==7) clearInterval(ti);
    }, 500);

};
```

```html
<!-- The element that 'End Of Results' will be added to it. 
     this must be the wrapper element that desired text will be added to it later. -->
<div id='must-capture'></div>
```

---

But, if you need to the code runs on IE9 or because any reason you like to use `timers`, you must combine two timers together. one for running in short delays (for example per 2 seconds) that you must run your above code there (for finding childs and check for existing 'End Of Results' text). in body of it, you must call `clearTimeout` of another timer that you must create it for run just after 5 minuts.

Answer (score 0):

Focusing just with the 5 Min delay. You can use javascript setTimeout() which gives a delay of 5 min.

```
var nodes = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('_64f'));

var bottomNode = nodes.filter(function isBottomNode(el, isForced = false) {
  return !!(
        (el &&  el.textContent && el.textContent.indexOf('End of Results')=== 0)
        || isForced === true
      );
    });
    return !!bottomNode.length;
}
```

Here is the set time out now,

```
var isForced = false;

setTimeout(function(){
     isForced = true;
}, 60*5);

// When calling the function
isBottomNode(el, isForced);
```